# ERROR 1123 (HY000): Can't initialize function 'mysql_firewall'; Plugin initialization function failed

Tags: mysql

I am trying to install and enable the mysql enterprise firewall on one of my linux servers. I need to run in manually, and am executing the linux_install_firewall.sql script.

When I do, when executing the line

mysql> INSTALL PLUGIN mysql_firewall SONAME 'firewall.so';

I get the following error message.

```
ERROR 1123 (HY000): Can't initialize function 'mysql_firewall'; Plugin initialization function failed.
```

In reviewing the mysqld.log, i see the following:

```
2017-02-09T19:40:17.033605Z 5 [ERROR] Plugin MYSQL_FIREWALL reported: 'Disable query cache before using the firewall.' 
2017-02-09T19:40:17.033655Z 5 [ERROR] Plugin 'MYSQL_FIREWALL' init function returned error. 
2017-02-09T19:40:17.033667Z 5 [ERROR] Plugin 'MYSQL_FIREWALL' registration as a AUDIT failed. 
2017-02-09T19:40:17.033686Z 5 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MYSQL_FIREWALL'
```

However, I have set query_cache_size = 0 in both my.cnf and directly in global variables. I've also restart the mysqld service.

I still see:

```
mysql> show variables like '%query_cache%'; 
+------------------------------+---------+ 
| Variable_name                | Value   | 
+------------------------------+---------+ 
| have_query_cache             | YES     | 
| query_cache_limit            | 2097152 | 
| query_cache_min_res_unit     | 4096    | 
| query_cache_size             | 0       | 
| query_cache_type             | ON      | 
| query_cache_wlock_invalidate | OFF     | 
+------------------------------+---------+
```

I'm still left without being able to install the firewall. Any ideas?